# How to use .htaccess to serve html file without extension if exists or fallback to index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Using apache .htaccess is it possible to achieve the following:

- A url without extension is called e.g. `/`, `/terms`, `/products/one`.
- If the relevant html file exists (`index.html`, `terms.html`, `products/one.html`) then it is served.
- If it does not exist, then `index.php` is called with a query string variable for e.g. `index.php?path=terms`.

How can we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up creating the below .htaccess code, see the comments for description:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# if any html exists based on current path then serve it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]

# if index.html exists then serve it if filepath is empty (checked by RewriteRule ^$)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [L]

# any thing left should go to index.php as path
# the RewriteCond !-f is used to avoid index.php loopback
# the RewriteCond !-d is NOT used so that if folder exists then it does not show directory listing
# may want to use some condition to show index.html in that folder if exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [L]
```

Checked all scenarios and seem to work!

For e.g.

- if `/` is called then it loads `index.html` if it exists, else it loads `index.php`
- if any path is called and its relevant html exists then it loads else `index.php` is called with that path
- made sure that static files like javascript and images etc also work
- made sure `php` files also work if they exist